# Get all records after value in one column changes

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that tracks users by their name, the group they belong to, the assignment they're working on, and the date they are given that assignment:

[image]

If a user is only ever given assignment 1, then they are in Group A, and I need to retrieve all of their records.

If a user is ever given assignment 2, then they are in Group B, and I need to retrieve all of their records from the first time that they were given assignment 2, inclusive:

[image]

So users 1, 2, and 3 are easy - I need all of their records.

But user 4 is the challenge. I need all of the records for user 4 from row 11, when they were fist given assignment 2, to row 13. It seems like this should be easy for me to get, but I just can't figure it out.

How can I write a query that gets the MAX(date) a value appears in a column, grouped by another column (in this case User Name), and selects all of the records for that user that contain the MAX(date) and all subsequent dates?

I tried this approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE ExecutedDate >= (SELECT MIN(t2.ExecutedDate)
                   FROM Table1 t2
                   WHERE t1.UserName = t2.UserName
                   AND t2.Group = 'A'
                   OR (t2.Group = 'B' AND t2.Assignment = 'Assignment 2'
                   GROUP BY t2.UserName
                   )
AND t1.Group = 'A'
OR (t1.Group = 'B' AND t1.Assignment = 'Assignment 2')
```

But I get the error that the subquery returned multiple values which is not allowed when using =, >,<,>=, =<, or the subquery is used as an expression.

I understand the error message, although I can't figure out how my subquery is returning multiple values. If someone could explain that to me, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT UserName
          ,MIN(CASE WHEN [Group] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [HasOnlyAGroup]
          ,MIN(CASE WHEN [Group] = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [HasOnlyBGroup]
          ,MIN(CASE WHEN [Group] = 'B' THEN [ExecutedDate] ELSE NULL END) AS [FirstExecutionInBGroup]
    FROM Table1 
    GROUP BY UserName
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource DS
OUTER APPLY
(
    -- for users, that has assigments from each group, we need to get the ID of the first assigment of group B
    SELECT TOP 1 [Row]
    FROM Table1 TMin
    WHERE DS.[UserName]  = Tmin.[UserName]
        AND DS.[FirstExecutionInBGroup] = Tmin.[ExecutedDate]
        AND DS.[HasOnlyAGroup] = 0 
        AND DS.[HasOnlyBGroup] = 0
    ORDER BY Tmin.[ExecutedDate] ASC
) MinID
INNER JOIN Table1 T1
    ON DS.[UserName] = T1.[UserName]
    AND
    (
        -- case 1: user has only A group assigments - show all rows
        (
            DS.[HasOnlyAGroup] = 1 AND DS.[HasOnlyBGroup] = 0
        )
        -- case 2: user has only B group assigments - retrieve rows from the first time that they were given assignment 2
        OR 
        (
            DS.[HasOnlyAGroup] = 0 AND DS.[HasOnlyBGroup] = 1
            AND
            DS.[FirstExecutionInBGroup] <= T1.[ExecutedDate]
        )
        -- case 3:
        OR
        (
            MinID.[RowID] <= T1.[RowID]
        )

    );
```

The query may need some change but the idea is to use `CTE` to get check if user has only A or B group assignments (or both). We are also getting their the first date of B assignment. Then in the `OUTER APPLY` we are getting the minimum `[Row]` value using the `[FirstExecutionInBGroup]` date value. After that, we have all of the values we need to perform your business logic.